# Burnup chart - tag criteria returns no results

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to create a management dashboard in VSTS with a burnup chart on it.

The dashboard lives in a "Senior Management" area, but this area has visibility of my "Delivery" area in which most of the work is done.

The burnup chart is currently set to show all PBIs in the delivery area.

I would like to filter by a particular tag ("Interchange"), so I've set a field criteria: Tags contains Interchange.

When I apply this, I get a message saying "Last time you checked, there were no results".

I've double checked and the PBIs definitely contain this tag. I've also tried filtering on a custom field called "Project" with the same value, and still get the same result.

When I remove the filter, I get the total number of PBIs in the delivery area again.

Why is the filter not applying as expected (i.e., only including those PBIs which contain the Interchange tag or Project value)?

Comment: What's the widget did you used in dashboard?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I'm using the standard VSTS analytics burnup widget

Comment: What if you remove the widget in your dashboard and add again? And What if you add all the teams of the project in configuration (since work items may be to be viewed by different teams)?

Comment: I've tried both of the above and get the same behaviour. I've also checked the work items' area path and they are all in the same area which is the one for the team I've configured the burnup for. I'm wondering if this is a bug? @MarinaLiu-MSFT

Comment: But I can not reproduce your issue, the tag criteria in burnup chart works for me. Can you reproduce the issue in other projects?

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue in my project

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the way ADO processes work item history. If you add a tag today, and filter your burnup on that tag, the work item will show on the chart as completed today (even though it may have been completed weeks ago). If you are displaying by iteration, those items won't show up at all, since your current iteration hasn't closed yet.